# split screen 8 parts

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to divide layout activity  to  8 ImageButton equivalent , when orientation changes background image stretch automatically  , How can i do some thing like uploaded image

Thank in advance

[image]
[image: trial 2]
this is my failed trial

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onFerakClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_ferak" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onHolyBookClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_holybook" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onMzahebClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mzaheb" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onShbhatListClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_shbhat" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onFactsImagePagerClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_facts" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onMapsGridClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_maps" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onSearchClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onProductsGalleryClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_product" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For all your image buttons set `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Answer (score 0):

set the `android:layout_weight="0.125"`

and I suggest converting all the widths like below:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

and try adding `android:layout_weight` to table rows also so that they can split the screen in half. `android:layout_weight="0.5"`

Edit:
how about you try this all with `LinearLayout`? Create two `LinearLayouts` (like rows) inside a `LinearLayout`(like your `TableLayout`) this way it will be guaranteed that android:layout_weight will work? Don't forget to set the android:orientation value of the `LinearLayouts` and according to that value set the widths or heights `0dp` and give `android:layout_weight` values instead.

Comment: please refer question i upload picture with result , Screen split but background image dos't stretched

Comment: I edited my answer, please check it, I am expecting your feedback

Comment: use match_parent at all times. ah wait! I guess I found the problem, you set the heights of your TableRows to wrap_content, change them also to match_parent!

Comment: Background image is not stretched

Comment: I know, did you try all the things that I've suggested

Answer (score 0):

Main changes:

- set width to 0dp and weight of all cells equally
- set height to match_parent, not to wrap_content
- set weight of table rows equally

Working xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onFerakClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_ferak" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onHolyBookClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_holybook" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onMzahebClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mzaheb" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onShbhatListClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_shbat" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onFactsImagePagerClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_facts" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onMapsGridClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_map" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onSearchClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onProductsGalleryClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_product" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Background image is not  stretched